# What is the correct action to take regarding questions that are not clearly poor quality until after you answer them?

Tags: discussion, rules, bad-questions

According to the Stack Overflow community rules/standards, what should be done in the following scenario?

You read a question that is not apparently bad just from reading it. Maybe the material is a bit dense, or the code is complicated so a casual glance over doesn't tell you if what is being asked is nonsense.

You start answering the question. It takes until you are invested and have used your critical thinking to realize that the person asking the question has no idea what they are talking about. Maybe they completely misunderstood the topic, or their code is full of holes, or they didn't include enough information to solve the problem; like they have a thousand little unspecified details that affect what things will or won't work but they never clarify. Maybe they think that something that isn't happening is happening, or they copied someone else's code and convincingly passed it off as their own.

You have written out an entire answer but now realize that their question should be downvoted and closed. Deeper inspection has shown it is obviously not up to community standards. At this point what do you do?

You have basically written out a whole answer so do you post your answer to the bad question anyway? Do you downvote and flag the question to be closed? Do you leave a warning for others that come after you? Do you do all of these things?

What is the correct procedure? Hopefully there will be rules, but it might just be opinion based.

Comment: I have to say, this is a *rare* edge case. In my experience. you can tell quickly whether a question has any merit. Sometimes this comes with experience. If you feel your answer adds value, post it. Otherwise, don't post it, and vote to close instead.

Comment: This has been happening to me more lately when answering questions that have been around 1 or more days, but have no comments or votes. This in itself may be the red flag though.

Comment: I am not in favor of answering bad questions.

Comment: So just downvote, flag to close, and move on?

Comment: One option *might* be to post the answer, then delete it. Then Downvote and Vote to Close the question. If the OP improves the question you *could* undelete (perhaps after editing) the answer. Just another option.

Comment: @Paulie. I think that is best. Don't give the bad question any positive reinforcement, but keep your hard work for later if it is actually improved.

Comment: @jpp 'this is a rare edge case', well, I'm afraid it's a bit more common than that:(

Comment: For instance, here's another one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50375755/758133

Comment: You missed a *very* common problem in your list of reasons why it ends up being bad: they didn't specify how to handle several edge cases. This is *extremely* common in list processing questions. What's worse is that such questions are commonly highly upvoted. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41164630/1394393 See the comments for discussion of the edge cases. The OP never clarified.

Comment: I have now included that in my list.

Comment: I assume that before you started writing your answer that you did a search to ensure that you weren't answering a dupe. If the answer is truly useful, then don't waste it. Do as picciano suggests in their updated answer: write a new question and self-answer it. And then flag the bad question as a dupe of yours so that it's easier to close.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> but now realize that their question should be downvoted and closed

Then do that.

And if you feel strongly about saving the effort that went into your "good" answer, maybe find a "good" question to put it on. Or ask a new question and self-answer it.

Comment: This does not address what should be done with the answer you have already put time and effort into – it is considered bad form to answer and then vote to close, but do you just throw out the answer?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to keep my answer short and brief since the OP already seemed to know what must happen and was really just looking for confirmation. But as I stated in the comments to the original question, I am not in favor of answering bad questions. I would not post the answer.

Comment: Yeah, and you would be doing The Right Thing™. Still it seems a shame to me to throw out the answer, and it is frustrating since you put effort into it in good faith. So maybe what we should be asking is how to weed out those questions in the first place.

Comment: Maybe take the "good" answer and find a "good" question to put it on? Or maybe even ask a new question and self-answer it?

Comment: That is an approach worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably leave a comment stating a few of the issue I found and asking the user to clarify.  If they failed to do so, I would vote to close as too broad.  Depending on the quality of the question, I might also choose to down vote, but I don't always.  But at the very least it is too broad as there are multiple potential issues that the question needs to address.